# Updating MS Azure SQL T-SQL stored procedures, functions, tables and Views online in a chromebook without SSMS?

Tags: azure, ssms, sql-server-data-tools, chromebook, azure-sql-server

I support some MS Azure cloud solutions that are Azure SQL + Azure Functions C# + Azure Web + JS frameworks.   I've been working remote from a Chromebook am able to support 90% of the solution with the exception of SQL stored procedures, tables and views as i cannot install SSMS or SSDT.

Azure has a Query Editor feature in my database i can use to test and query my data, but it won't let me update DDL.  The feature warns that it has limited capabilities and to open SSDT for full features.

Any good option to edit my MS-SQL DDL online/web based without a Microsoft Client?

incidently... Is it possible to update Azure SQL DDL from a Azure Function in code with enough rights?

Comment: Create a Windows VM in Azure that you can RDP onto.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Linux applications and install Azure Data Studio.

Firstly, you need to enable Linux applications on your Chromebook. You can do so in Settings, Linux (Beta). The Chromebook will then take a little while setting up the environment.

Once done, download the latest version of Azure Data Studio and download the `.deb` version of the file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver15.

Once Downloaded, open Files on your Chromebook and then copy it to the Linux Files Folder you will now see over on the left hand side. Then open your applications menu and open the (new) terminal application. Then run the command:

```sh
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Answer yes if there are any updates to install. Then run:

```sh
sudo dpkg --install azuredatastudio-linux-1.16.1.deb
```

Obviously replace the name of the file if it differs, and I assume that you put the file in the linux area not in a directory.

You may need to run `sudo apt install -f` afterwards, to fix any dependancies, and then   the `dpkg` command again.

Once done, you can then find Azure Data Studio in your applications and run it; like so:

[image]

*Note, some commands are harder to do on a Chromebook if you retain the Search key as the Search Key, and don't enable the Function buttons are the top. If you do, I suggest setting up some custom shortcut keys for command commands. For example, on my Chromebook, I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for execute query.*

Comment: Thanks for this. might be my best and only option. might need to upgrade my chromebook however.  I'm checking if can perform DDL commands over an Azure function in code and if so .. might write my own Azure SQL DDL api in c# with enough security.

Comment: Doesn't Azure Data Studio require an Intel processor? The OP didn't specify what their Chromebook is running. Also, ADS is only officially supported on 4 distributions, none of which are running on Chromebooks AFAIK

Comment: The Linux environment itself is a version of Debian, which ADS runs well on. I've had no problems with VS Code or ADS on Chromebook (apart from the keyboard layout)

Comment: As for the processor, no, you don't need an Intel Processor. AMD will be fine. I don't recall off the top of my head, but I suspect this won't work if the OP is using an ARM Chromebook.

Comment: By "Intel" I meant the Intel instruction set - x86/x64. And yes, ADS _does_ have a list of supported Linux distros. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver15#supported-operating-systems Just because It's working for you does not mean it will work for OP, and being outside the supported list means things could break with a future update.

Comment: Had missed that list, my bad, @alroc . However, there are a lot of people that use  VSCode on Chromebook. ADS is effectively a downstream version of VSCode. True, Microsoft won't support any problems you encounter, but any problems I have found I have on Ubuntu as well. But at the end of the day the OP is asking how they can connect to SQL Server on a Chromebook, and unless they build their own application, then this is a very viable solution, even if not officially supported.